# Socket data encoding Python3

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, python-sockets

I was trying to write a quick and dirty script to test this device and send it an ASCII command. I'm able to use Putty and send it commands so I know that I'm understanding the API correctly, however, my python script isn't working how it's intended to work, but I'm not getting the device to recognize the commands. 
Am I encoding the data incorrectly?

```
import socket

edsIP = "10.5.80.150"
edsPORT = 50002
MESSAGE=b'set:6;'

srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
srvsock.settimeout(3) # 3 second timeout on commands
srvsock.connect((edsIP, edsPORT)))
srvsock.sendall(MESSAGE)

data = srvsock.recv(4096) 


srvsock.close()
```